# which is the best javascript lib for google maps and iphone 

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, pastrykit

i want to develop a map site on iphone use google maps v3

thanks

**updated**

i find one :[PastryKit](http://www.nxfx.com/blog/iphone-development/apples-pastry-kit-iphone-javascript-toolkit/) which i think better than iui and jqtouch ,

but i can't find its doc ,

so did you know the PastryKit's doc  ?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sencha.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest jQuery or prototype.  These are lightweight frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

i use gmaps.js. this is power lib for goole map.
https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/
this js lib is complete for polyline,polygon,route,marker,...